# Static control as field in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, static, controls

If I create a class, e.g. MyContainer and have a Label as a field and make it static, then I create two instances of MyContainer and add it to my overall Scene.

I would have thought if after creating the two instances of MyContainer, I updated the text of the Label via a public method, that it would update it for both Labels, but it is not behaving like this.

I also don't know how FX would deal with static controls (or even nodes in a more general sense) as it states in the API that only one instance of a node can exist in the scene graph?

I've added an example below, as I seem to have refined the problem slightly:

```
public class ApplicationLoader extends Application {

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        ButtonPane bp1 = new ButtonPane();

        ButtonPane bp2 = new ButtonPane();

        bp1.modify(); //modifies b1 Button text of bp2?

        VBox root = new VBox(20, bp1, bp2);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static class ButtonPane extends HBox {

        private static Button b1; //even though b1 is static it appears to be added twice?
        private static Button b2 = new Button("Button 2");
        private Button b3;

        public ButtonPane() {
            setSpacing(10);
            b1 = new Button("Button 1");
            b3 = new Button("Button 3");
            this.getChildren().addAll(b1, b2, b3);
        }

        public void modify() {
            b1.setText(b1.getText() + " Modified");
        }
    }

}
```

When you declare Button b2 as static and initialise it at the point of declaration it only appears in the 2nd instance of ButtonPanel, i.e. bp2. With Button b1 that is also static but initialised in the constructor it gets added to both. However, only the 2nd instance bp2 is modified, resulting in this:

[image: static FX behaviour demo]

Comment: You've answered your own question: the same node can't appear in the scene graph more than once. So it makes no sense to make a node static.

Comment: I guess another way to put this: what do you mean by "it would update it for both Labels"? If the label is static, then there is only one label.

Comment: Yes but it let's you have static nodes and add them twice in two different instances of a parent containing class, so how is this possible?

Comment: As you already noticed, it's not possible. You'd be adding (or trying to add) the same instance of a node to two different parents. The API documentation expressly forbids doing that, so the actual effect is not defined (probably it only appears in the last parent it was added to, but there's no guarantee at all that you would observe that behavior). Think of it this way: what would you expect `myStaticNode.getParent()` to return? Again, it just makes no sense at all to make a node static.

Comment: Imagine I have a class, e.g. MyContainer that extends HBox and this has a static field of type Label. If I create two instances of MyContainer and add them both to a root node on a scene then the Label is appearing in both instances even though its static and if I update its text its only updating one of them.. Very strange?

Comment: Not strange at all. You are trying to add the label (just one label) to two different places in the scene graph. Again, the API specification expressly forbids this, so the results are completely undefined. You either leave the scene graph in an inconsistent state, or the implementation removes it from the first parent when you add it to the second.

Comment: But basically: " MyContainer that extends HBox and this has a static field of type Label". Why? Why on earth would you do this?

Comment: Because I wanted to showcase to somebody the exact principle of not being able to add the same node twice to a scene graph and therefore thought static would ensure it would just appear once for its most recent parent. I. Not suggesting its good practice I'm trying to ask why the label is appearing twice when I do not think it should be! If you don't know the answer then move on and let someone else explain precisely why this is occurring.

Comment: Well.. it doesn't appear twice, does it? It certainly doesn't when I do it. Can you post an [MCVE]?

Comment: But with the buttons you reference as `b1` and `b3` you create new ones every time you call the constructor. So you are not adding the same button every time.

Comment: Ah.. yes I just realised this and my stupidity.. like you say I initialise Button b1 and add it to the HBox and then come along and reinitialise it and add that new object to the HBox, so that's why the call to modify updates bp2 as both bp1 and bp2 will be holding a reference to the latest static object I initialised.

Answer (score 0):

A node can only appear once in the scene graph. If you make a node reference static, then there is only one instance of that node. If you try to add that node to two different parents, the results are not defined. The most likely behavior (and the one that's observed if you actually try this) is that if the node is already a child of one parent, then when you add it to a second parent it will be removed from the first.

Here is a SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AddLabelMultipleTimes extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


        MyContainer myContainer1 = new MyContainer("Button 1");

        MyContainer.setLabelText("Label");

        MyContainer myContainer2 = new MyContainer("Button 2");

        VBox root = new VBox(5, myContainer1, myContainer2);



        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 180);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


    }

    public static class MyContainer extends HBox {

        private static int count = 1 ;

        private static Label label = new Label();
        private Button button ;

        public MyContainer(String buttonText) {
            button = new Button(buttonText);
            button.setOnAction(e -> setLabelText("Count "+(count++)));
            getChildren().addAll(label, button);
            setSpacing(5);
            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        }

        public static void setLabelText(String text) {
            label.setText(text);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

In this example, the static label first is added to `myContainer1`. Then it is added to `myContainer2`. When that occurs, it is removed from its previous parent, so it only appears in the second container as seen in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I see - I think it may have something to do with when the static field is initialised - take a look at my edited original post that now includes  code example and a screenshot.